# SELECT unique values based on grouping on a different column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users_to_groups_hist](
[user_number] [int] NULL,
[group_number] [int] NULL,
[version_number] [int] NULL,
[user_id] [int] NULL,
[last_update] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[users_to_groups_hist] VALUES

(22195,20017,1,22076,'2018-05-09 06:14:02.170')
,(22195,20020,1,22076,'2018-05-09 06:14:02.173')
,(22195,20023,1,22076,'2018-05-09 06:14:02.173')
,(22195,20025,1,22076,'2018-05-09 06:14:02.180')
,(22195,20029,1,22076,'2018-05-09 06:14:02.180')
,(22195,20029,2,20451,'2019-11-12 10:39:21.237')
,(22195,20025,2,20451,'2019-11-12 10:39:21.237')
,(22195,20023,2,20451,'2019-11-12 10:39:21.237')
,(22195,20020,2,20451,'2019-11-12 10:39:21.237')
,(22195,20017,2,20451,'2019-11-12 10:39:21.237')
,(22196,20028,1,22076,'2018-05-10 03:14:15.087')
,(22196,20029,1,22076,'2018-05-10 03:14:15.087')
,(22196,20010,1,22076,'2018-05-10 03:14:15.083')
,(22196,20025,1,22076,'2018-05-10 03:14:15.087')
,(22196,20025,2,20451,'2018-10-15 11:57:12.477')
,(22196,20053,2,20451,'2018-10-15 11:57:12.477')
,(22196,20053,3,22586,'2020-03-20 11:02:48.810')
,(22196,20025,3,22586,'2020-03-20 11:02:48.810')
,(22196,20025,4,22194,'2020-06-24 00:20:02.523')
,(22196,20053,4,22194,'2020-06-24 00:20:02.523')
,(22196,20053,5,20300,'2020-09-02 19:31:38.900')
,(22196,20025,5,20300,'2020-09-02 19:31:38.900')
,(22196,20035,5,20300,'2020-09-02 19:31:38.900')
,(22196,20009,5,20300,'2020-09-02 19:31:38.900')
,(22227,20012,1,22076,'2018-07-09 04:56:09.987')
,(22227,20025,1,22076,'2018-07-09 04:56:09.990')
,(22227,20026,1,22076,'2018-07-09 04:56:09.990')
,(22227,20028,1,22076,'2018-07-09 04:56:09.990')
,(22227,20035,1,22076,'2018-07-09 04:56:09.990')
,(22227,20029,2,20825,'2018-07-11 17:48:36.967')
,(22227,20028,2,20825,'2018-07-11 17:48:36.967')
,(22227,20025,2,20825,'2018-07-11 17:48:36.967')
,(22227,20025,3,22100,'2018-07-19 19:44:06.490')
,(22227,20028,3,22100,'2018-07-19 19:44:06.490')
,(22227,20029,3,22100,'2018-07-19 19:44:06.490')
,(22227,20043,3,22100,'2018-07-19 19:44:06.490')
,(22227,20043,4,22076,'2018-11-02 12:19:44.480')
,(22227,20025,4,22076,'2018-11-02 12:19:44.480')
,(22227,20025,5,22452,'2019-09-24 13:18:36.950');
```

In the above table, a user_number can be added and/or removed from a group_number by a support person which is populated in the user_id column.
I want to be able to query for each user_number and the unique group_number they belong to.
I want to also display the version_number when they were added and/or removed from a group_number and the last_update

My Query below works for a single user_number but goes out of whack when I remove the where clause:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM
(
   SELECT ug.user_number, 
       ug.group_number, 
       ug.version_number, 
       ug.user_id, 
       ug.last_update, 
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ug.group_number
       ORDER BY ug.group_number)
FROM users_to_groups_hist ug
WHERE ug.user_number = 22227
) AS x
WHERE x.rn = 1
ORDER BY x.user_number;
```

Essentially, for each user_number I want to be able to report out the unique group_number that user_number belongs to but if I remove

```
where ug.user_number = 22227
```

then the query does not return the correct group_number for each user_number.

The desired output I am looking for is the following:

```
user_number   group_number  version_number  user_id      last_update
22195          20017               1         22076    2018-05-09 06:14:02.170
22195          20023               1         22076    2018-05-09 06:14:02.173
22195          20029               1         22076    2018-05-09 06:14:02.180
22195          20025               2         20451    2019-11-12 10:39:21.237
22195          20020               2         20451    2019-11-12 10:39:21.237
22196          20010               1         22076    2018-05-10 03:14:15.083
22196          20025               1         22076    2018-05-10 03:14:15.087
22196          20028               1         22076    2018-05-10 03:14:15.087
22196          20029               1         22076    2018-05-10 03:14:15.087
22196          20053               4         22194    2020-06-24 00:20:02.523
22196          20009               5         20300    2020-09-02 19:31:38.900
22196          20035               5         20300    2020-09-02 19:31:38.900
22227          20012               1         22076    2018-07-09 04:56:09.987
22227          20025               1         22076    2018-07-09 04:56:09.990
22227          20026               1         22076    2018-07-09 04:56:09.990
22227          20028               1         22076    2018-07-09 04:56:09.990
22227          20035               1         22076    2018-07-09 04:56:09.990
22227          20029               2         20825    2018-07-11 17:48:36.967
22227          20043               3         22100    2018-07-19 19:44:06.490
```

I am assuming some kind of grouping over row over partition which I have never done and can't figure out...

Please help.

Comment: Show some desired output.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: partition by user_number order by date? It definitely makes no sense to do both with the same column though.

Comment: @philipxy - what is it about the question that bimini07 needs to correct? or is it all of those things??

Comment: @Trubs That's a standard comment of mine. I think it's clear what parts can reasonably be said to be already satisfied & which not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query as-

```
SELECT x.*
FROM
(
   SELECT ug.user_number, 
       ug.group_number, 
       ug.version_number, 
       ug.user_id, 
       ug.last_update, 
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ug.user_number,ug.group_number
       ORDER BY ug.version_number desc)
FROM users_to_groups_hist ug
) AS x
WHERE x.rn = 1
ORDER BY x.user_number;
```